# "CheckVirtualFileExists" exception occur when IIS application pool recycled

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, iis-7

I have published my site in IIS which is developed with ASP.Net Website in VB.Net code. All site application pool is recycled in certain period. My problem with session values.

I have used session state mode as "In Proc". I have a problem when site is recycling it, my session values got lost. So i planned to change into "StateServer". Now i got another problem says that "checkvirtualfileexists" exception.

I have used many menus are created using dynamically. When we are doing navigation it says "checkvirtualfileexists" exception. URL had been changed anonymously and application tried to navigate. So file exists problem arrived.

All feed backs and discussions are most welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you use an Out Of Process State Server (either a server or a SQL dB) I'd recommend it's a different server to the IIS box.

Comment: Or even better get rid of sessions and make it stateless, otherwise scaling is much harder.

Comment: How can i make it as stateless? What do you mean different server to the IIS box. You mean to host in different server?